# Google Cloud Virtual Machine: Resize to a bigger machine without changing external IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, vps

Last time I resized to a bigger machine, my IP changed making a lot of trouble with my service. 
Do you know if there is any way of resizing without changing the external IP address?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a static ip address. So you can use this static ip with another instance.
The ephemeral IP address can not be reassigned

Comment: Thanks Alexandre. I just promoted the ephemeral external IP address to static. Hope that keeps the same ip during resizing. Thanks your directions.